# Registration problem in DJANGO REST FRAMEWORK

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a User model and ı want to create user register API. I created API but it doesn't work. I think  I did something wrong but ı can't fix it.
it looks like on swagger UI like this:
[image]

It doesn't show the body item in swagger UI

How can ı fix this register problem?

view.py:

class RegistrationView(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication,)

```
# permission_classes = (XHROnly,)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=False):
        user = serializer.save()
        user = authenticate(email=user.email, password=serializer.validated_data['password1'])
        if user is not None:
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return Response({'status': 'success', 'token': token.key,
                                 'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request': self.request}).data},
                                status=201)
            else:
                return Response({'status': 'success', 'token': token.key,
                                 'user': UserSerializer(user, context={'request': self.request}).data},
                                status=201)
        else:
            return Response({'status': 'error', 'errors': serializer.errors}, status=203)
    else:
        return Response({'status': 'error', 'errors': serializer.errors}, status=203)
```

serializers.py:

```
class RegistrationSerializer(Serializer):
    full_name = CharField(max_length=200)
    email = EmailField(max_length=100)
    password1 = CharField(max_length=100)
    password2 = CharField(max_length=100)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['password1'] == data['password2']:
            return data
        else:
            raise ValidationError('Girdiğiniz şifreler uyuşmamakta.')

    def validate_full_name(self, value):
        return value

    def validate_email(self, value):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(email=value)
            raise ValidationError("Bu email kullanılmaktadır.")
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return value

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(email=validated_data['email'], full_name=validated_data['full_name'],
                                        password=validated_data['password1'])
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        pass
```

When ı use Postman ı got this errors
[image]

Comment: at what line you getting errors response?

Comment: I don't know, somethings wrong but what?

Comment: It's weird that the username field appears on the error list, because you don't have that field declared in your serializer and you aren't using a model serializer, I think that the error maybe it's coming from the create method but at that point I'm pretty sure that your application should throw a 500 error response.